# Server Error 500 Localhost in xampp

Tags: 14.04, xampp

Im trying to access the folder.Im using ubuntu 14.4 i have installed xampp trying to access folder `http://localhost/comment/`

But i got error like

Server error!

```
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

localhost
Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
```

I have given all permission to the folder how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http status code 500 itself probably won't tell you what went wrong.

Most http status codes are relatively "talkative", they tell you what's wrong in some detail. Take for example "404 Not Found". With this code, the server tells the client (for example, a web browser), "what you asked me to send you is not at that address". Or "403 Forbidden" ("You are not allowed to access that address"). Or, to take an example out of the range of problems on the server, "507 Insufficient Storage" ("The server does not have enough storage capacity left to do what you asked for").

In contrast to that, "500 Internal Server Error" is (somewhat deliberately) relatively vague. It just tells the client, "Something went wrong at the server's side of things", nothing more. It's like a "catchall" for everything that goes wrong while processing the client's request. It's used if the server (or the server's administrator) doesn't know what more to tell the client - or it doesn't *want* to tell the client anything more, because the details are none of the client's business ;)

So, "500 Internal Server Error" can be caused by a multitude of different things going wrong. To get further information you can consult the error logs of your server. In a typical setup, the server keeps two kinds of log files. In the *access log*, it notes down every request from a client it gets ("At time such and such a client from that IP address asked for that URL"). You mostly use the access log for statistic evaluations.

The other kind of log is the *error log*. Here, the client notes down everything that goes wrong. So you should take a look in your server's error log and search for the time the error occured. That should give you a log message that tells you more about what went wrong.

Where the server stores its logs depends on the server's configuration. The directives you should be looking for in the server's config files are `AccessLog` and `ErrorLog`.