# Phpmyadmin error HTTP 500 after fresh install

Tags: lamp, phpmyadmin

[image]In Ubuntu 16.10  freshly installed LAMP server and installed PHPMYADMIN
when i open localhost/phpmyadmin I'm getting HTTP 500 error
PHP version 5.6
MySQL Version 14.14 Dist rib 5.7.16
Apache 2 version 2.4.18
and i have tried almost all the solutions that i got online none worked

Even if I install all of the other packages except this one and try to install phpmyadmin, it returns a 500 server error.

Thank you

Comment: Apart from `phpmyadmin` can you serve other pages from `/var/www/html`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Server Error 500 Localhost in xampp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610768/server-error-500-localhost-in-xampp)

Answer (score 0):

Let's try installing PhpMyAdmin dependencies. I presume you're using PHP 7.

```bsh
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext
```

Then restart Apache:

```bsh
sudo apache2 restart
```

Comment: did that, its still the same

Comment: Im using both php7 and php5.6

Answer (score 0):

You should check your `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`.

Locate

`php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/phpseclib/` in `apache.conf`.

Now change the `/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/` to `/usr/share/php/php-gettext/`

Comment: phpmyadmin works fine with php7 but magento doesnt so when i change it php5.6 its still the same

Comment: Go to `/var/log/apache2/error.log `. What are the errors you are getting?