# Error 500 ubuntu index.php setting

Tags: server, permissions, lubuntu, apache2

I'm getting this error after putting my file inside html directory and I'm confused about this setting. I think I have to open the `index.php` file, but I'm getting a 500 error. Let me know about any error you notice please.

[image: Structure of directory]

[image]

This is data from `/etc/apache2/sites-available/fullstack1.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName www.fullstack1.xyz
    ServerAlias fullstack1.xyz
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/fullstack1

    <Directory /var/www/html/fullstack1/public/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
     </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    LogLevel warn
</VirtualHost>
```

This is data from `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Server Error 500 Localhost in xampp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610768/server-error-500-localhost-in-xampp)

Comment: did you enable php? i.e. is it in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`. Not sure which version for you look for php7.4.conf ,for example, in `/etc/apache2/mods-available` and enable via `sudo a2enmod php7.4` (but use your version numbers).

Comment: info.php tells me i'm using PHP Version 7.4.26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a couple of items to look at in the `fullstack1.conf` file:

1. Your `DocumentRoot` should point to the directory that visitors to the site will start from which, based on the `<Directory>` entity, should be:

   ```
   /var/www/html/fullstack1/public
   ```
2. The final slash in the `<Directory>` entity is unnecessary:

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/html/fullstack1/public>
   ```
3. If you are running a modern version of Apache, these two lines can be removed from the `<Directory>` entity:

   ```
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   ```

   These permission statements are now handled with the `Require` statements.
4. If Apache does not know what to serve when people visit the bare domain, it will default to showing the directory structure or present an error. As you’re running a PHP-based site, you can add this line immediately after `DocumentRoot`:

   ```
   DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
   ```

   This will look first for `index.php` in the `/public` directory and fail first to `index.html` if the PHP file does not exist, then to `index.htm`.

Once these items are taken care of, restart (or reload) the Apache server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This should give you what you need